# Can I connect the ground to the light fixture

Tags: electrical

I have an old house and am updating the wiring. The old wiring had hot and neutral only, and some of the hanging lights only have two connections also. However they are hanging from metal chains. Can I connect the ground to this metal? Or should I cap the ground until I replace the fixture?

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of the boxes involved please?

Comment: The house is 130+ years old and there are no boxes exposed as it is a large plaster floral on the ceiling. I placed a box in the ceiling above, but there would be no way to access it from below. And the light itself has no grounding wire either

Comment: is it oxidized (black) chain, then no

Comment: If the junction boxes are metal they might be grounded. Sometimes ground wires were run separately, or a metal-jacketed cable was used. You have to measure to know for sure.  Retrofitting grounds **is allowed** as of NEC 2014.  There is no point to connecting ground wires to each other if there isn't a ground path back to the panel.  Creating an island of grounds only shares ground faults, it doesn't ground anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bare copper wire ground is just that, yes you can secure it on the box, or any metal object.  That is what it is all about. That is exactly where it goes, you, the floor,the building, the Earth.

Take care.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed as much. Just wanted to make sure the light fixture/chain itself was an ok connection.

Answer (score -1):

"And the light itself has no grounding wire either"
Based on this info it seems the ground wire referred to is in the ceiling. Residential wiring 130 years ago wasn't grounded so if the ground wire is in the ceiling it must have been updated at some point with 14/2 NM w/ground or 14/2 armored cable.
Assuming it was properly installed you can connect the bare copper ground from the NM cable directly to the light fixture. If it's grounded  through an armored cable and attached to the box you installed you can run a bare copper ground from the cable/metal box directly to the light fixture.
In order to help ensure the ground connection I would run a long bare ground wire from the ceiling, lace it through the chain and attach it directly to the body of the light fixture with a self-tapping screw.

Comment: The OP says there is no place on the fixture to connect the bare ground wire.  That is why the question is asked in the first place.  In quote, "and some of the hanging lights only have two connections."  She wants to know if she has to cap the  ground or just hook it up for now to some other metal/chain etc until she replaces the fixture at sometime.

Comment: @Meta_Alchemy - that is precisely why my answer said it is okay to attach the ground **directly** to the light fixture. Since there is no ground wire on the light it can attach to any metal portion of the light that has continuity through the fixture.